# Technical Reason For Declaring A List with New vs. without New in Apex

Tags: apex, list, new

What is the technical reasoning behind the two ways to declare a List? I know that new tells the compiler to create an instance of the List class, but what does the second one do differently? Also, what is the technical reason that collections require the new word to determine a new instance of them, but variables don't?

```
List<String> listOfStrs = new List<String>();
List<String> listOfStrs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*tl;dr*: variables are stored in a symbol table, and this table only stores a small value, either a primitive or a reference, and the full object for non-primitives are stored in the heap. Assignment of the reference to the value in the symbol table is always achieved via the assignment operator `=`, so we're really talking about three mechanisms: declaration, assignment, and heap allocation. You may also want to read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm).

---

Apex, like most object-oriented languages, has three types of memory: code, stack, and heap. When you call a method or enter a block, you create a "stack frame", which is added to the stack to keep track of recursive method calls, and it is here that these symbols are stored for use in the code that's executing. When the block ends or the method returns, the stack frame is discarded.

In Apex, this stack space is really small, just 1,000 items. If you exceed this limit, you get a Stack Overflow error. Stack frames allow multiple instances of the variable to exist during a recursive method call, which is why you need a new frame for each block.

Note that class and static storage do not count towards the stack limit, and each have a unique scope as well; the static scope stores symbols at the class level (a global value), and the class scope stores symbols at the instance level; one unique copy per instance of that class.

Within the frame, you have a "symbol table". This simply keeps track of the declared variables (symbols) and the value they hold. The symbol table can only hold 8 bytes of data for each symbol.

For primitives, like Boolean, Integer, etc., this value can be stored directly. However, when using assignment from one variable to another, or passing into a method, this value is always assigned by reference; no additional heap is consumed.

Strings, Dates, Maps, and so on, must occupy more than 8 bytes of data. In order to store larger values, we need a way to store them elsewhere. The primary storage for these values is called the *heap*.

When you use the `new` keyword, or use some factory methods (e.g. `Date.newDate`), some heap space is allocated, and a *reference* is returned. If you do not use the assignment operator, the reference will be lost as soon as the next statement in the current method is called. This behavior allows us to use an instance of a class for just one line of code:

```
new HelperClass().doSomethingImportant();
```

We also have the "string pool." This is a trick borrowed from Java, whereby strings are immutable, and each string is stored in a "string pool"; creating a new string with identical content will result in the same reference being returned, so that two symbols with the same string don't occupy any additional space. Strings themselves count towards the heap limit, but this invisible string pool does not.

In reality, there's only one way to declare a variable: `dataType variableName` (as well as the comma variant, `dataType variable1, variable2`, a shorthand to create multiple variables at once). This statement creates one or more symbols in the local stack frame's symbol table. If no value is assigned, these symbols will be null.

The code that reads `variableName = value`, this sets the symbol in the symbol table to the new value. You can combine these concepts to write more concise code. As an example:

```
String hello = 'hello', world = 'world', helloWorld = hello+' '+world;
System.debug(helloWorld); // 'hello world'
```

Note: you should really only declare one variable per line of code at most, but the language allows multiple declarations at once.

As other answers state, there are several different initializers you can use, depending on the object involved.

- sObject: (field1=value1, field2=value2, ...)
- List/Set: { value1, value2, ... }
- Map: { key1 => value1, key2 => value2, ... }

Note that initialization is not assignment; this is strictly achieved through the `=` operator. We are also not supposed to be able to assign to a symbol that hasn't been added to the symbol table for any stack frame or static property.

So, the statement:

```
List<String> name = new List<String>();
```

Has three parts: (1) adding a symbol to the symbol table, (2) constructing a new object in the heap, and (3) assigning the returned reference to the symbol's value.

While the latter version:

```
List<String> name;
```

Has just one part: (1) adding a symbol to the symbol table. The value for the symbol will be null.

---

Edit: some descriptions may be slightly off from actual execution of Salesforce internals. They are described here are more "industry standard" nomenclature as I understand compiler logic (which is admittedly a bit rusty), but hopefully this helps highlight the technical differences of *why* things are the way they are.

Comment: This explanation was exactly what I was looking for. Been awhile since college and I could not, for the life of me, find anything applicable to Apex's idiosyncrasies in this regard. Thank you!!!! :)

Comment: Would this be a fair summary? Variables (Integer, String, Boolean, etc.) are small enough to exist in the 'stack' memory of the code, while collections (Set, List, Map) are too big, and require storing in the 'heap' memory. Therefore, they need the new keyword to explicitly tell the code to allocate this memory in the heap, and then you're assigning a reference to that memory to the List. cont...

Comment: List<String> listOfStrings is the part that is declaring what its going to be, new List<String>() is constructing a new version of it in the heap, and then = is assigning the reference that is returned from the construction to the value of listOfStrings.

Comment: @natashabowman It sounds like you got the gist of it. There's a lot more that goes on under the hood, but we're not told most of it, for obvious reasons. Still, I'm glad you found this enlightening!

Comment: Awesome, thank you much!

Answer (score 2):

Declares a new NON NULL list. This list is empty but not null:

```
List<String> listOfStrs = new List<String>();
```

Declares a new typed variable, but at this point it is null:

```
List<String> listOfStrs;
```

It is safest to initialize your list using the first technique if possible, because this will eliminate any null pointer errors.

Just for completeness, here are some other ways you can declare a list. This one is functionally the same as the first example:

```
String[] listOfStrs = new String[]{}
```

This one is preinitialized:

```
String[] listOfStrs = new String[]{'hi mum'};
List<String> listOfStrs = new List<String>('hi mum');
```

Adding in sfdcfox's comments to make them a bit more permanent:

```
String[] listOfStrs = new String[0]; //to create an empty list, 
String[] listOfStrs = new String[5];  //to create an array of 5 items, all indexes are null.
```

Also:

```
new List<Integer>(5); //creates an array of 5 nulls.
new List<Integer>{5}; //creates a List of just 1 value, the number 5.
```

Comment: Also: `String[] listOfStrs = new String[0];` to create an empty list, or `String[] listOfStrs = new String[5]` to create an array of 5 items, all indexes are null.

Comment: Oh, and while I have this window, I forgot to mention that `new List<Integer>(5)` creates an array of 5 nulls, while `new List<Integer>{5}` creates a List of just 1 value, the number 5.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing here isn't two different ways to declaring a variable, but rather the difference between declaring a variable

```java
// variable declaration/definition
// <type> <identifier>;
List<String> stringList;
```

and *initializing* a variable

```java
// variable initialization, declaration with an extra step
// <type> <identifier> = <type instance>
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
```

This isn't just limited to lists, and it's not just limited to Apex. It's a pretty common concept/feature in programming languages.

`stringList` in my example is also still a variable. `List<String>` is simply the data type, a *collection* type.

There are some situations where you need to initialize instead of just declare (like `final` variables, though they can also be set in a constructor), and as Caspar pointed out, initializing means you're less prone to Null Pointer errors. Beyond that though, there's not much difference.

As for the `new` keyword, as you know, it's how new instances of classes are created. It's how class constructors get called, and collections are Classes.

It's not that collections are the outliers here, but rather that things like Integers, Strings, Decimals, Booleans are special. They're [primitive types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm). They're simple enough that their instances can be directly typed out as "literals" and understood by the compiler. Everything else requires using the `new` keyword. That's a bit oversimplified, but should be close enough.

Although Date/Time/DateTime are primitive types, they can't be assigned literal values (you need to use a method like `DateTime.newInstance()` to get an instance of those, rather than using the `new` keyword)

#### Takeaways

- Collections describe a set of data types
- A variable needs to have a data type declared (this is what "strong typing" is), and that type can be list/set/map (or any number of other things)
- Most data types need to use the `new` keyword to get a new instance of that type
- The exception are the "primitive types", which we can't use the `new` keyword for
- Strings, Integers, Booleans, Decimals, Ids, Doubles, and Longs are special primitive types that can be "literal" values in a program